# Unable to set data type datetime(3) in MySQL 5.5.60

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert a field from DATATIME to DATETIME(3). Server version i s 5.5.60-MariaDB. I am trying to do this with workbench 8.0. I get the "No Changes Detected" message and the data type remains DATETIME.

I have tried the following code to change the date type:

```
ALTER TABLE `ALLOCATED_HISTORY`
MODIFY COLUMN `DATE_EFFECTIVE` DATETIME(3) DEFAULT NULL;
```

I get a Error Prasing DLL error when I try to view the table in alter table in workbench.

Comment: Can you share the error message here? And I've used the same query on version 5.6.42 and it works without any errors. Maybe you can consider updating your version?

Comment: the title says mysql 5.5.60 and the question says 5.5.60-MariaDB - which is it mysql or mariadb?

Answer (score 1):

Mysql 5.5 can't store microseconds, this feature was introduced in 5.6.4.

> as of MySQL 5.6.4, any fractional part in a value inserted into a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column is stored rather than discarded.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html